# defun vs defmacro and backquote vs list

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros, backquote

While looking to exclude the uses of the `list` *function* through the **backquote** substitutes in `defmacro`s, my attempt failed when combined with the `let` and ``let*` recipe, together with the `gensym` function (as a source of `unintern`ed symbols, as illustrated somewhere else), to create temporary variables - but the latter is not the issue.

A running **MWE [EDITED: inserted macroexpand]** is the following.

```
(defun w (a &optional b) ; line 1
  (let ((z (gensym)))
   `(let* ((,z (if (integerp ,b) '((,a ,b)) '((,a))))) ,z)))
    ⇒ w

(eval (w 3)) ; line 2
    ⇒ ((3))
(eval (w 3 0)) ; line 3
    ⇒ ((3 0))
```

The `w` is a `defun` above: when the optional `integerp` second argument is present, return the pair as a "***doubled***" list; otherwise return only the first argument, also inside two pairs of parentheses.

Now comes the tricky part: need to replace the `defun` with a `defmacro` (`m` for `w`).

```
(defmacro m (a &optional b) ; line 4
  (let ((z (gensym)))
   `(let* ((,z (if (integerp ,b) `((,a ,b)) `((,a))))) ,z)))
    ⇒ m

(macroexpand (m (+ 1 2) 0)) ; line 5
    ⇒ list: Symbol's value as variable is void: a
```

And also attempt to return the evaluation of `(+ 1 2)`, i.e., `((3 0))`. The loop shows the above `line #4` is **faulty**.

Next use instead simple quotes, i.e., `'((,a ,b))`.

```
(defmacro m (a &optional b) ; line 6
  (let ((z (gensym)))
   `(let* ((,z (if (integerp ,b) '((,a ,b)) '((,a))))) ,z)))
    ⇒ m

(macroexpand (m (+ 1 2) 0)) ; line 7
    ⇒ (((+ 1 2) 0))
```

Okay, but there is no evaluation of the argument: not acceptable.

```
(defmacro m (a &optional b) ; line 8
  (let ((z (gensym)))
   `(let* ((,z (if (integerp ,b) (list (list ,a ,b)) (list (list ,a))))) ,z)))
    ⇒ m

(macroexpand (m (+ 1 2) 0)) ; line 9
    ⇒ ((3 0))
```

Finally, use the `list` function for a change: this time it works, yet there is one `list` too many.

The problem is then how can `line #4` keep its minimalistic form using (back)quotes, so that `line #5` would result as `line #3` - using `defmacro` versus `defun`. There is a ``(...` within ``(---` pattern. that might be the cause.

Appreciate all answers. Thank s.

Comment: The Right Way to debug and test macros is [`macroexpand`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Expansion.html)

Comment: Note, you're supposed to quote the argument you're passing to `macroexpand`, otherwise you're calling `macroexpand` on the result of evaluating that form. So that would be `(macroexpand '(m (+ 1 2) 0))`.

Comment: Also, the backquote is very useful, but sometimes you need to ask yourself whether it's really helping or not. In this case, I (personally) think your code would be easier to read if the inner backquote were a regular list.

Comment: @Malabarba: In the context of the "recipe" (the result is eventually `set...`), the tests with `macroexpand` need call "on the result of evaluating that form", which is a `(let* ((G...`. Dropping `gensym`, by the use of `defmacro` instead of `defun`, what could the body of `m` be other than `\`(if (integerp ,b) \`((,,a ,,b)) \`((,,a)))` (without two commas and) with "regular lists"? thanks.

Comment: @sjb No. :-) The result of evaluating that form is one of the branches of the `if` clause. *Roughly put*, when a macro form is evaluated, it is first macroexpanded (which yields a `(let* ...)`) and then the result of the expansion is evaluated (so the `let*` gets evaluated). Therefore, your call to `macroexpand` is pointless (you're calling it on something like `'((a)))`. What you want to do when experimenting with macros is call `(macroexpand '(m (+ 1 2) 0))`. This will expand the form *without* evaluating it, and will allow you to see what's going on.

Comment: @Malabarba Yes. ;-) Put `'(m (+ 1 2) 0)` and see only dots.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Using the macro defined in your answer (since that's the working version), if I call `(macroexpand '(m (+ 1 2) 0))` I get the following ```(let* ((G89271 (if (integerp 0) (\` (((\, (+ 1 2)) (\, 0)))) (\` (((\, (+ 1 2)))))))) G89271)```, which is exactly what I would expect to get.

Comment: `(let* ((G45287 (if ... ... ...))) G45287)`

Comment: Put your cursor on that and press enter, it will fully expand.

Answer (score 5):

It's not necessary to use a backquote inside another, that's the beauty of it.

```
(defmacro m1 (a &optional b)
  (let ((z (gensym)))
    `(let ((,z (if (integerp ,b)
                   (list ,a ,b)
                 (list ,a))))
       ,z)))
```

But that isn't correct yet. The purpose of `z` isn't to add another variable for the fun of it, but to protect `b` from being evaluated more than once (because doing that might have side-effects or be costly). You are not doing that. Here's how to do it.

```
(defmacro m2 (a &optional b)
  (let ((z (gensym)))
    `(let ((,z ,b))
       (if (integerp ,z)
           (list ,a ,z)
         (list ,a)))))
```

This demonstrates the difference:

```
(let ((v 1)) (m1 1 (cl-incf v))) => (1 3)
(let ((v 1)) (m2 1 (cl-incf v))) => (1 2)
```

You do not have to do the same for `a` because, even though it appears twice, only ever one occurrence is evaluated.

Comment: Costs when it is over... For now something like `m3 (a &optional b z v1 v2) \`(let* (,z ,v1 ,v2) (if (integerp ,z) ...)` digs for me. Thanks for the correct variant.

Answer (score 3):

[Nested backquotes require more commas.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429521/common-lisp-double-backquote-unquote-quote-unquote-sequence/%22nested%20backquotes%20pattern%22)

```
(defmacro m (a &optional b) ; line 4
  (let ((z (gensym)))
   `(let* ((,z ,b)) (if (integerp ,z) `((,,a ,,z)) `((,,a))))))
```

Comment: Another possibility is to do: ```,`((,a ,b))```.